# Mysql adding index cause timeout

Tags: mysql

When adding to table of over 20m rows an index using alter table I'm geting discconected after a while from mysql .
I'm using mysql 5.6 and this is the log file I'm getting:

```
  END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
    ============================
    InnoDB: ###### Diagnostic info printed to the standard error stream
    InnoDB: Error: semaphore wait has lasted > 600 seconds
    InnoDB: We intentionally crash the server, because it appears to be hung.
    2014-08-31 21:52:17 890  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 2192 in file srv0srv.cc line 1748
    InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
    InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
    InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
    InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
    InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
    InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
    InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the cfg file "my" .
I changed the inno db bufeer to 1500mb and now all good so far.

hope it will help others.